# ANGULAR-UI-ROUTER: Resolve state from URL

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui, angular-ui-router

I'm making an app with dynamical states, and sometimes I need to resolve the state name from the url.

e.g.: I have `/dashboard/user/12268` and I need to get the state `'dashboard.user'`.

Is there any way to do this with the tools given by `ui-router`? I can't find out how to do this right now...

I'm making an app with dynamic module loading with requireJS. At first time there is no problem because user is sent to login state. After login, I use require to load only the states the user has access to. But when the user reloads the page, I load the modules again, and need to resolve the url to a state, and there's the problem. I've started trying with urlMatcherFactory but can't resolve them.

The state is loaded after the URL resolution.

The flow is (after the refresh of page `http://localhost:8090/index.html#/dashboard/user/12268`):

- bootstrap the app (without states)
- at this point, `ui-router` has been loaded
- get the states the user has access to, and register them (these states are registered **after** config phase)
- find out if i have a state that matches the given url to redirect to there. This is where I'm stuck.

To load states after application bootstrap, I've used a variation of [Ben Nadel's solution](http://www.bennadel.com/blog/2554-loading-angularjs-components-with-requirejs-after-application-bootstrap.htm) that includes states and constants.

My `data-main` in RequireJS has this initialization code:

```js
require.config({
    // REQUIREJS CONFIGURATION
});

require(['app'], function (app) {
    app.bootstrap(document);

    var ng = angular.injector(['ng']);
    var $window = ng.get('$window')
    var $q = ng.get('$q');

    var appStorage = $window.localStorage;
    var loadedManifests;

    try {
        loadedManifests = JSON.parse(appStorage.getItem('loadedManifests'));
    } catch(e) {
        loadedManifests = [];
    }

    if (!angular.isArray(loadedManifests) || loadedManifests.length === 0) {
        $q.all([
                app.loadManifest('login/manifest'), //loadMainfest function loads the states for login
                app.loadManifest('logout/manifest') //load states for logout
            ])
            .then(function () {
                app.injector.get('$rootScope').$evalAsync(function () {
                    app.injector.get('$state').go('login');
                });
            });
    } else {
        var promisesArray = [];

        for(var i = 0; loadedManifests[i]; i++) {
            promisesArray.push(app.loadManifest(loadedManifests[i])); //load all manifests registered on localstorage
        }

        $q.all(promisesArray).then(function(){
            //TODO: Stuck. Get URL from querystring and resolve to valid state, or redirect to /login
        });
    }
});
```

The`loadManifest` function registers all after-bootstrap elements on my app (services, factories, controllers, routers, ...).

Thanks for your help,
Alx

Comment: Please post what you have so far

Comment: I'm making an app with dynamic module loading with requireJS. At first time there is no problem because user is sent to login state. After login, I use require to load only the states the user has access to.

But when the user reloads the page, i load the modules again, and need to resolve the url to a state, and there's the problem. I've started trying with urlMatcherFactory but can't resolve them

The state is loaded after the URL resolution

Comment: UI-Router Extras Future States can manage your scenario for you: http://christopherthielen.github.io/ui-router-extras/#/future

Answer (score 17):

https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/issues/1651

You can expose the internal state implementation by using the `.decorator` hook on `$stateProvider`.  You can decorate any property of the state builder; I chose 'parent' arbitrarily.

---

```
app.config(function($stateProvider) { 
  $stateProvider.decorator('parent', function (internalStateObj, parentFn) {
     // This fn is called by StateBuilder each time a state is registered

     // The first arg is the internal state. Capture it and add an accessor to public state object.
     internalStateObj.self.$$state = function() { return internalStateObj; };

     // pass through to default .parent() function
     return parentFn(internalStateObj); 
  });
});
```

---

Now you can access the internal state object using `.$$state()`, e.g.

```
var publicState = $state.get("foo");
var privateInternalState = publicState.$$state();
```

---

Second, loop over each state in $state.get() and test them against your URL fragment.

```
angular.forEach($state.get(), function(state) { 
  var privatePortion = state.$$state();
  var match = privatePortion.url.exec(url, queryParams);
  if (match) console.log("Matched state: " + state.name + " and parameters: " + match);
});
```

Comment: Best. Solution. Ever.

Thank you!

Comment: In the search part, adding `if (!state.$$state) return;` would be good, because I had a _global_ abstract state which didn't have that property and caused an error.

Comment: This is really awesome! The url should not start with an hashtag (#) to get a match (e.g. /foo instead of #/foo ).

Answer (score 1):

Finally I've had to make a small modification on ui-router's `$state` service to get to the solution.

It results that the states stored in the service have more information that the one given on the `$state.get()` method. So I iterated over them to get a state that matches with my URL:

```js
/**
 * @ngdoc function
 * @name ui.router.state.$state#fromUrl
 * @methodOf ui.router.state.$state
 * 
 * @description
 * A method to resolve a state and its parameters from a given URL
 *
 * @returns {boolean} Returns a state that matches with the given URL, or undefined if no match
 */
$state.fromUrl = function(url) {
  if(!angular.isString(url)) {
    //Only valid strings allowed
    return undefined;
  }
  
  
  var keys = objectKeys(states);
  //Iterate over all states
  for(var i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
    var state = states[keys[i]];
    var stateArgs = state.url.exec(url);

    //If the state's URL does not match then stateArgs will be false
    if(!!stateArgs) {
      return {
        name: state.name,
        args: stateArgs
      }
    }
  }

  return undefined;
};
```

Regards,
Alx

Comment: where does "states" come from in objectKeys(states)?

Comment: @PascalDeMilly I think you can consider that _states_ is the result of calling _$state.get()_

Answer (score 0):

To get @Chris T solution to work for me I am doing this inside a Service:

```
app.service('Helper', ['$state', '$location',
    function($state, $location){

       var services = {};

       services.stateIs = function(state_name){
          var current_path = $location.$$path;
          var state = $state.get(state_name);

          if(state){
              var state_regexp = state.$$state().url.regexp;
              return state_regexp.test(current_path);
          }else{
              return false;
          }
       }

       return services;
    }
]);
```

So later I can inject Helper anywhere and do this:

```
if(Helper.stateIs('app.user')){
    //yeah 
}
```

Answer (score -2):

The current state can be obtained from $state service. like `$state.current`
Check this api http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/site/#/api/ui.router.state.$state

Comment: it could be added as comment

Comment: @pankajparkar this statement contains an answer along with a reference to api doc. why would it be a comment?

Comment: how does it resolves OP s question..could you explain me

Comment: Yes. Using $state is the answer. And how would you claim it to not being an answer but a comment rather?

Comment: In this case, `$state.current` is a void state because states are registered after the configuration phase

Comment: Yes. As I can see, you have edited your question to make it more clear. If you need to get state from context, then use $state.get(stateOrName, context) P.S refer given api for the same