# How to match current url to an ui-router state url

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, state

I need to check if my current URL match or not with an state URL (using ui-router). The issue here is that I am loading dynamically all my states, so when the user refresh a page this URL is not loaded yet so I am being redirected to the otherwise URL.

I am planning to load all my states in the **`otherwise`** function and check the one that math with my current URL and load it right away, so maybe in this way I **won't be redirected** to my `default` URL.

Example: 
My current URL: **asd/5/it-is-a-slug**
My state URL:   **/asd/:id/:slug**

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

The way to go here, I'd say, is to use UI-Router built in
**`$urlRouterProvider.deferIntercept(defer)`** for that. Check some other:

- [can we add dynamic states to $stateprovider with already existing states in ui-router angular.js](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29422780/1679310)
- [AngularJS - UI-router - How to configure dynamic views](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29013914/1679310)
- [Angular - Dynamically Choose Starting State](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30477922/1679310)

The point is the

#### [$urlRouterProvider.deferIntercept(defer)](http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/site/#/api/ui.router.router.$urlRouterProvider#methods_deferintercept)

> Disables (or enables) deferring location change interception.
>
> If you wish to customize the behavior of syncing the URL (for example, if you wish to defer a transition but maintain the current URL), call this method at configuration time. Then, at run time, call $urlRouter.listen() after you have configured your own $locationChangeSuccess event handler.

There is [a working example](http://plnkr.co/edit/fYJpLcadgk3jpnOci1JS?p=preview)

in a **`config()`** phase we will defer execution:

```
app.config(function ($locationProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $stateProvider) {
  
    $urlRouterProvider.deferIntercept();
    ...
```

In a **`.run()`** phase we will load dynamic stuff:

```
$http
  .get("myJson.json")
  .success(function(data)
  {
    angular.forEach(data, function (value, key) 
    { 
      var state = {
        "url": value.url,
        "parent" : value.parent,
        "abstract": value.abstract,
        "views": {}
      };
      
      angular.forEach(value.views, function (view) 
      {
        state.views[view.name] = {
          templateUrl : view.templateUrl,
        };
      });

      $stateProviderRef.state(value.name, state);
    });
    // Configures $urlRouter's listener *after* your custom listener
    
    $urlRouter.sync();
    $urlRouter.listen();
  });
```

Example [in action](http://plnkr.co/edit/fYJpLcadgk3jpnOci1JS?p=preview)

Comment: Agree with Radim, deferIntercept is the thing to use.  For the other half of the question (how to get a state based on a url), see this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29892353/angular-ui-router-resolve-state-from-url/30926025#30926025