# Get state given url with ui-router AngularJS 1.x

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

How can I convert current URL to the corresponding state? The result state will be used for state transition using $state.go.

Example:
http://localhost/auth/enterprise/

Registered route:

```
{
"stateName": "auth.context",
"url": ":context"
}
```

**Result**: auth/enterprise/ => auth.context

Example:
http://localhost/auth/enterprise/esdrubal

Registered route:

```
{
"stateName": "auth.context",
"url": ":context/:username"
}
```

**Result**: auth/enterprise/esdrubal => auth.context

Comment: what are you trying to achieve? some sort of callback URL for Authentication?e.g. for OAuth ? In that case no client-side JS is able to do this

Comment: What I'm trying to do is convert current URL to a registered state, and use that state on $state.go to proceed the transition.

Answer (score 0):

**SOLUTION**:

> You can expose the internal state implementation by using the .decorator hook on $stateProvider. You can decorate any property of the state builder; I chose 'parent' arbitrarily.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/30926025/5485700