# How get $state with absolute URL in Angular

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I'm trying to get the `$state` of a **URL**.

Basically I want to do the **reverse** of :

```
$state.href('user.home.view', {}, {absolute: true});
```

Instead of get The `Abs URL` I want to get The state's name;

I want to pass a **Abs URL** to a function and then get a valid `$state` in the angular's project.

Comment: when in doubt ... `console.log($state)` and inspect what's there

Comment: check the updated answer if that may help you somewhat. Not exactly what you wanted, but may suffice your need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a data field named `$uiView` attached to the `ui-view` element, it contains the view name and the associated state. You can get the state like this:

```
elem.closest('[ui-view]').data('$uiView').state
```

or even

```
elem.inheritedData('$uiView').state
```

So, in your controller:

```
 .controller('State1Ctrl', function ($state) {
      console.log(elem.closest('[ui-view]').data('$uiView').state); // state1
      console.log($state.current.name)  ;//will give the state name as well.  
});
```

**UPDATE:**

`Your issue:` https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/issues/1651

**WORKAROUND:**
[ANGULAR-UI-ROUTER: Resolve state from URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29892353/angular-ui-router-resolve-state-from-url/30926025#30926025)

You can expose the internal state implementation by using the .decorator hook on `$stateProvider`. You can decorate any property of the state builder; somebody chose `'parent'` arbitrarily.

```
app.config(function($stateProvider) { 
  $stateProvider.decorator('parent', function (internalStateObj, parentFn) {
     // This fn is called by StateBuilder each time a state is registered

     // The first arg is the internal state. Capture it and add an accessor to public state object.
     internalStateObj.self.$$state = function() { return internalStateObj; };

     // pass through to default .parent() function
     return parentFn(internalStateObj); 
  });
});
```

Now you can access the internal state object using .$$state(), e.g.

```
var publicState = $state.get("foo");
    var privateInternalState = publicState.$$state();
    //Second, loop over each state in $state.get() and test them against your URL fragment.

    angular.forEach($state.get(), function(state) { 
      var privatePortion = state.$$state();
      var match = privatePortion.url.exec(url, queryParams);
      if (match) console.log("Matched state: " + state.name + " and parameters: " + match);
    });
```

Comment: Just updated the question... I want to **pass** an URL an get a valid $state in the application... is that possible?

Comment: I don't know about that, since the documentation mentions none of what you are expecting for now. We are talking about absURL which may or may not resolve to a state. There may be some hack around though.